# Identifying kernel modules

Tags: linux, kernel-modules

How do I get more information about a kernel module, like a long description?

For example, I can see kernel modules like `lp` or `hid`, but those short codes do not mean anything useful to me.

Answer (score 5):

OK, found it. The command `modinfo` gives available information on a module, though it seems only what is available, so e.g. `modinfo snd_seq` gives me a long description, but `modinfo lp` does not, probably depending on whether the developers included the information or not.